# How do I find out what macOS app is using a shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, apple-mail, macos-catalina

So on macOS I want to setup Mail to have <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to reply all but it isn’t letting me. Looks like another app or something is conflicting with that combination.

I don’t see it in the preferences keyboard section, any ideas on how else I can find out what app is using that shortcut?

Comment: It's not going to be an app, it's going to be something global - menu bar item, background task etc. Cmd/Shift/R is the default for reply all, so you shouldn't need to add it in system prefs. There are apps that can give you a list of commands for any frontmost app, but not for global intercepts. Alternatively, try cmd/opt/shift/R.

Comment: When you say something is conflicting, what do you mean?  What does happen when you press that key combo outside of Mail?  And what happens when you try to assign that key-combo to that menu item inside of the Keyboard preferences?  I thought app-specific shortcut keys (assigned in Keyboard) overrode global ones.

Comment: App-specifics don't override globals. Try replacing any command as an app shortcut that already exists as a global.

Answer (score 1):

[ShortcutDetective](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/labs/) solves your problem. It's free, simple, and to the point.